# ID card magnetic stripe encoding

Tags: c#

I need to be able to print ID cards with magnetic stripes and smart card. So I need to be able to print these from a wpf app,   Any suggestions?

Comment: Smart Cards and Mag Stripes are two different worlds

Answer (score 1):

You would probably need to find a magnetic stripe reader/writer that plugs into your computer via USB and creates a COM port.  Then you can communicate with it using serial communications to tell it what to do using the .NET `SerialPort` class.

Comment: is there any stimulator/dll/ocx to encode data to magnetic stripe, so that it should work with any devices

Comment: I would think each device has its own way of communicating.  Usually applications like these are designed with specific hardware in mind.